# Get type of elements in a List derived from List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, generics, types

Lets say that I have classes which derive from `List<T>`:

```
public class StringList : List<String> {}
public class NameList : StringList {}

public class IntList : List<int> {}
```

Now I have a generic method which expects type `List<T>`:

```
public static Method<T>() { ... }
```

How can I determine the type of elements contained in a list in this method, i.e. how to get the generic argument type in a derived class?

For base class I can call `typeof(T>.GetGenericArguments()`, but for derived class it returns zero size.

PS: In my concrete situation the type which method expects is not exactly `List<T>`, but `IList`.

Comment: As an aside, it's usually a bad idea to subclass `List<T>`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt). Otherwise, you can check the interfaces and look for `IList<T>` to grab the generic argument of string

Comment: @Rob Good point, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the method like this:

```
public static void Method<T>(List<T> thing) (or IList<T>)
{
    //Here, `T` is the type of the elements in the list
}
```

Of if you need a reflection-based check:

```
public static void Method(Type myType) 
{
    var thing = myType.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
        .Where(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

Note that you'll need appropriate sanity checks here (rather than `FirstOrDefault()` and 0 indexing)

Comment: Thanks again, the reflection is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want both the type of the list and the element type of the list at compile time, your `Method` must have two generic definitions like this:

```
public static void Method<T, E>(T list) where T : List<E> 
{ 
    // example1
    // T is List<int> and E is int

    // example2
    // T is NameList and E is String
}

Method<List<int>, int>(new List<int>());   //example1
Method<NameList, string>(new NameList());  //example2
```

Comment: This is a good solution if we choose not to use the reflection, but in my case that one extra parameter matters (without the method argument which I do not have).